# Rational to floating point

Tags: java, c++, c, floating-point

Consider a rational number represented by the structure below.

```
struct rational {
    uint64_t n;
    uint64_t d;
    unsigned char sign : 1;
};
```

Assuming an IEEE-754 binary64 representation of `double`, how can the structure be converted to the nearest `double` with correct rounding? The naive method of converting `n` and `d` to `double` and dividing them clearly compounds rounding error.

Comment: C or C++? Pick one...

Comment: It doesn't matter. If it bothers you, I'll add Java to the list.

Comment: No, it really doesn't. The question is about maths.

Comment: The question is rather more difficult that you would like it to. This twitter thread is about this very topic, and no 140-character answer came out. https://twitter.com/stephentyrone/status/648566625185218561

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: As far as I know, C and C++ have the same or sufficiently similar rules for arithmetic (I don't know about Java). On the other hand, I agree that specifying the language actually being used is a good thing. And on the other other hand, if this is just a maths question, why is it in a programming site?

Comment: No, the question is about an implementation of division of integer that results in double with minimal loss of precision. Such an implementation depends on the particular language you use. If it was math, you could just divide the numbers and have no loss of precision, as math is abstract.

Comment: a `uint64_t` may not be fully representable as a `double` so how would handle that? ie `LLONG_MAX > DBL_MAX`

Comment: You say converting `n` and `d` to `double` "clearly" compounds rounding error. Some support for that assertion would be helpful. Converting to `long double` might be sufficient *if* `long double` has more precision than `double`, which is not guaranteed. For example Microsoft's compiler makes them both 64 bits, which is perfectly legal as far as C is concerned. (I don't know about Java; why is the "java" tag there?)

Comment: While I am afraid that the OP might have unwittingly invited the wrath of three fine large SO sub-communities, the questions is extremely valid, interesting and indeed, mostly language-agnostic. But this does not mean that it is not programming-related, as the IEEE 754 standard is very much about being available in programming languages, with more or less baggage attached.

Comment: @NathanOliver: The maximum value of `uint64_t` is exactly 2^64-1, which cannot exceed `DBL_MAX`. `LLONG_MAX` could in principle do so, but that's exceedingly unlikely. 2^64-1 likely isn't *exactly* representable as a `double`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I mentioned that `double` means IEEE-754 binary64 in the context of this question. The maximum exponent of binary64 is 1023, so it is clearly greater than UINT64_MAX.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: The C standard does not require to use IEEE754 floating point.

Comment: @KeithThompson: The "java" tag is there due to childish spite, apparently.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for this information. I do not think that it contradicts the fact that IEEE 754 is very much about being available in programming languages.

Comment: @KeithThompson If we assume that the conversion of a `uint64_t` that is out of range to a `double` has a maximum error of 0.5 ULP and their division has also a maximum error of 0.5 ULP as governed by IEEE-754, then it seems quite clear that the maximum error when combining these is more than 0.5 ULP. Being not a maths scholar, I can not formally prove this, but I have a strong suspicion that this is the case. Since IEEE extended-80 can represent all 64-bit integers, using x87 to divide the numbers will be exact, but that is not the point.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: There are many embedded systems which use other formats or behave non-compiant (e.g. rounding) due to performance reasons with software-FP. Not sure if C++ or Java allow other implementations, however. One of the problems when specifying multiple languages.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Nevertheless, the solution could be different between languages. Suggested `long double` doesn't exist in Java, whereas you could theoretically, if you're not concerned about time, use the `BigDecimal` class in Java to divide the numbers to whatever precision you want and only *then* convert it to double.

Comment: @KeithThompson a `double` typically only has a 52 bit mantissa so it cannot cover all possible values of a 64 bit unsigned integer without losing precision.  see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: @RealSkeptic what you mentioned hints at something interesting from the maths POV that was the real purpose of the question. How much precision do you need to round exactly to double? How do you prove that?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Yes, I'm aware of that, and I mentioned it in my comment. I was replying to your assertion that you could have `LLONG_MAX > DBL_MAX`. You could, if `unsigned long long` is ludicrously large (say, 1024 bits), but you still couldn't have `UINT64_MAX > DBL_MAX`, since `uint64_t` is required to be exactly 64 bits.

Comment: @KeithThompson that I did mess up on.  unfortunately I can no longer edit it.

Comment: @68ejxfcj5669 You can't round *exactly* to double, but the loss of precision that results from converting the two `long` values to `double` (when their magnitude is too large) can be avoided, so you will have only one loss of precision to answer for.

Comment: Reading the comments, this question is either too broad or "primarily opinion based". It apparently leads to heavy discussion. Both are valid close reasons. And as given, it is language-agnostic and possibly not even related to programming, but to mathematics (IIRC there is a field which does include such subjects).

Comment: You can always do this the old-fashioned way, which is guaranteed to work correctly.  A `double` is just a number of the form `+/-1 * 1.<52 bits here> * 2^<11 bit exponent>`.  Traditional long division is fairly straightforward for binary numbers.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Indeed, multi-precision long division can be used to compute the dividend to an arbitrary number of digits. However, how many digits do we need before we can round the intermediate representation to the nearest binary64 number? This is a challenging question commonly tackled in math libraries for things such as `sin`, but I believe the answer for division should be simpler.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer was implicit in my response: you need 52 bits.

Comment: @LouisWasserman even though I'm not an expert, I'm pretty sure that's not true. Consider if the intermediate fraction is something like (in decimal) 0.5000000000000000000000000000000001 vs 0.4999999999999999999999999 and you want to round to 1 digit.

Comment: Rounding in decimal digits, instead of binary, makes no sense.  Forget decimal digits.  IEEE 754 `double` representation only cares about 52 bits of precision in the mantissa.

Comment: But to get the nearest 52-bit value could require evaluating beyond 52 result digits for a reason similar to what I described in decimal. A digit at the 52+k-th position could cause the rounding direction to differ.

Comment: @Olaf You can close this question if StackOverflow is not the right forum to ask it. I apologize if I have offended anyone.

Comment: Not particularly. 53 bits will let you decide whether to round up or down, just as once you have .5xyz you can round up and .4xyz you can round down.  You don't need any more bits than that.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Now that I think of it, you may be correct. This is because long division yields the exact value of each digit and not an approximate of the result (like an iterative algorithm such as reciprocal multiplication). I will accept your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of achieving the desired result is to perform the division in integer space. As standard C/C++ does not offer a 128-bit integer type (while some tool chains may offer this as an extension), this is not very efficient, but it will produce correct results.

The code below generates 54 quotient bits and a remainder, one bit at at time. The most significant 53 quotient bits represent the mantissa portion of the `double` result, while the least significant quotient bit and the remainder are needed for rounding to "nearest or even" according to IEEE-754.

The code below can be compiled as either a C or a C++ program (at least it does with my tool chain). It has been lightly tested. Due to the bit-wise processing, this isn't very fast, and various optimizations are possible, especially if machine-specific data types and intrinsics are employed.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct rational {
    uint64_t n;
    uint64_t d;
    unsigned char sign : 1;
};

double uint64_as_double (uint64_t a)
{
    double res;
#if defined (__cplusplus)
    memcpy (&res, &a, sizeof (res));
#else /* __cplusplus */
    volatile union {
        double f;
        uint64_t i;
    } cvt;
    cvt.i = a;
    res = cvt.f;
#endif /* __cplusplus */
    return res;
}

#define ADDcc(a,b,cy,t0,t1) (t0=(b), t1=(a), t0=t0+t1, cy=t0<t1, t0=t0)
#define ADDC(a,b,cy,t0,t1) (t0=(b)+cy, t1=(a), t0+t1)
#define SUBcc(a,b,cy,t0,t1) (t0=(b), t1=(a), cy=t1<t0, t1-t0)

double rational2double (struct rational a)
{
    uint64_t dividend, divisor, quot, rem, t0, t1, cy, res, expo;
    int sticky, round, odd, sign, i;

    dividend = a.n;
    divisor = a.d;
    sign = a.sign;

    /* handle special cases */
    if ((dividend == 0) && (divisor == 0)) {
        res = 0xFFF8000000000000ULL; /* NaN INDEFINITE */
    } else if (dividend == 0) {            
        res = (uint64_t)sign << 63; /* zero */
    } else if (divisor == 0) {
        res = ((uint64_t)sign << 63) | 0x7ff0000000000000ULL; /* Inf */
    } 
    /* handle normal cases */
    else {
        quot = dividend;
        rem = 0;
        expo = 0;
        /* normalize operands using 128-bit shifts */
        while (rem < divisor) {
            quot = ADDcc (quot, quot, cy, t0, t1);
            rem = ADDC (rem, rem, cy, t0, t1);
            expo--;
        }
        /* integer bit of quotient is known to be 1 */
        rem = rem - divisor;
        quot = quot + 1;
        /* generate 53 more quotient bits */
        for (i = 0; i < 53; i++) {
            quot = ADDcc (quot, quot, cy, t0, t1);
            rem = ADDC (rem, rem, cy, t0, t1);
            rem = SUBcc (rem, divisor, cy, t0, t1);
            if (cy) {
                rem = rem + divisor;
            } else {
                quot = quot + 1;
            }
        }
        /* round to nearest or even */
        sticky = rem != 0;
        round = quot & 1;
        quot = quot >> 1;
        odd = quot & 1;
        if (round && (sticky || odd)) {
            quot++;
        }
        /* compose normalized IEEE-754 double-precision number */
        res = ((uint64_t)sign << 63) + ((expo + 64 + 1023 - 1) << 52) + quot;
    }
    return uint64_as_double (res);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. As soon as I realized that long division generated the exact digits, I knew the solution would look like this. Cheers!